# how to convert content between two html elements into image?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to convert html content as image, is it possible?

```
<div class='temp'>
  <img class='tt'> 
     <div><img class='tt1' /></div>
</div>
```

I want to save whole div(class= 'temp') as a image with its content.

Comment: I might not be 100% clear on what you are asking. But, you can use the Print Screen button on the top right of your keyboard and then paste it into a image editing software such as paint.

Comment: Fortunately, there is PrintScreen Button in the keyboard for that purpose.

Comment: dear i dont want to take a print shot of that, i want to convert whole html content into image, it is same as screen shot, i want to do that using javascript/ ajax/ jquery / php

Comment: where is the code to do this supposed to run?

Comment: i want to do that in PHP / jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need some kind of HTML render engine. Usually this means porting something like webkit to run on your server and having it draw to a bitmap. Not trivial by any means

Really need more details about exactly what you are trying to do (ie, is this your OWN html or arbitrary web sites, is the code to be php on a server or via javascript [not possible] .. are you willing to use a thumbnail service , etc)

Comment: Maybe you could get an external service to do it for you... does browsershorts.org have an API?

Comment: dear i want to save customized design of user as a simple single image,